# syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ')'

Tags: laravel, eloquent, select-options

How to fix this error code? idon't know what to do

```
 <select class="form-control" id="status_member-" name="status_member" required="required">
                            <option value="{{($pelanggan->status_member === 'silver') ? '$pelanggan->status_member' : 'silver' }}"{{($pelanggan->status_member === 'silver') ? 'selected' : '' }} >{{($pelanggan->status_member === 'silver') ? '{{ $pelanggan->status_member }}' : 'Silver' }}</option>
                            <option value="{{($pelanggan->status_member === 'gold') ? '$pelanggan->status_member' : 'gold' }}"{{($pelanggan->status_member === 'gold') ? 'selected' : '' }} >{{($pelanggan->status_member === 'gold') ? '{{ $pelanggan->status_member }}' : 'Gold' }}</option>
                            <option value="{{($pelanggan->status_member === 'diamond') ? '$pelanggan->status_member' : 'diamond' }}"{{($pelanggan->status_member === 'diamond') ? 'selected' : '' }} >{{($pelanggan->status_member === 'diamond') ? '{{ $pelanggan->status_member }}' : 'Diamond' }}</option>
                            <!-- <option value="{{$pelanggan->status_member}}" selected="selected">{{$pelanggan->status_member}}</option> -->
                            </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value="{{($pelanggan->status_member === 'silver') ? '$pelanggan->status_member' : 'silver' }}"` check is redundant because whatever may be the value of $pelanggan->status_member value will be silver always

The same applies for the display value `{{($pelanggan->status_member === 'silver') ? '{{ $pelanggan->status_member }}' : 'Silver' }}` is redundant

Same for the other two options.

Try the below

```
<select class="form-control" id="status_member-" name="status_member" required="required">
    <option 
        value="silver" {{ $pelanggan->status_member === 'silver' ? 'selected' : '' }} 
    >Silver</option>
    <option 
        value="gold" {{ $pelanggan->status_member === 'gold' ? 'selected' : '' }} 
    >Gold</option>
    <option 
        value="diamond" {{ $pelanggan->status_member === 'diamond' ? 'selected' : '' }} 
    >Diamond</option>
    <!-- <option value="{{$pelanggan->status_member}}" selected="selected">{{$pelanggan->status_member}}</option> -->
</select>
```

Comment: thank you, it's solved but in scrtipt of selected i changes with this {{ $pelanggan->status_member === 'Silver' ? 'selected' : '' }}